# iPhone storyboard to iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I understand that it would be better in the longrun if I redesign my app for the ipad, but is there an easy way to upscale my views for the ipad from iphone dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, otherwise you just make an iPhone app and have it run 2x on the iPad. it's not universal without two storyboards/Xibs.